# Ambiguous Question in Mendelson's Intro to Topology

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I'm reading Bert Mendelson's *Intro to Topology* and there's a lemma that's kinda worded ambiguously.

So the lemma goes as follows

**Lemma** Given a subset $A$ of a topological space and a point $x \not \in \bar A,$ then $x \not \in F$ for some closed set $F$ containing $A$.

---

My question is: Is Mendelson saying that this lemma is true for ***all*** sets $F$ such that A $\subset$ F?

**OR**

Is he saying that this lemma says that ***there exists*** a set $F$ satisfying the above properties?

Comment: The latter; this is clear from his use of *some*. Had he meant the former, he’d have said *each closed set* or *all closed sets*.

Comment: That's what I thought. The former doesn't make sense because if you let your space be $\mathbb{R}$ and let $A = (4,5)$ and $F=[0,10]$ and let $x \in \bar A = [4,5]$ then we can pick $x \in [0,10]$ such that $x \not \in [4,5]$

Comment: I don't have Mendelson's book and I wonder why he stated it this way. Of course if you take $F=\bar A$, then certainly $F$ is a closed set containing $A$, and $x\not\in F$. But, perhaps he has not yet proved that $\bar A$ is closed, and that is why he needs the Lemma? If $x\not\in\bar A$ then $x$ is in some open $U$ that misses $A$ (and $\bar A$), and the complement $F$ of $U$ is (some) closed set missing $x$ (and containing $\bar A$): Indeed if $y\in U$ then $U$ shows that $y\not\in\bar A$. But, he is not saying "for all", indeed the entire space $X$ is closed and contains both $x$ and $A$.

Comment: Your question is not about topology, but  about the general meaning of the phrase "for some" in a mathematical statement. Saying that a property is satisfied for some $F$ (which may be any mathematical object, e.g. a number, a set, ...) means that there exists $F$ having this property. This is just the same as in ordinary language usage: "Some cats are grey."

Answer (score 2):

He clearly says **some** so it's certainly not meant to hold for all such subsets.

The proof is obvious of course: take $F=\overline{A}$ and you're done. This can only mean that in this text he hasn't shown yet that $\overline{A}$ is closed, maybe it's a step towards that fact?